# grep string after what I specify

Tags: linux, grep

I am using grep and I want to get the data after my string I specify. I want to get the string after what I specify. If I grep "label:" I get "label: blue label:red label: green". I want to get just the colors. If I say grep -o I get all the labels. If I say -l it says (standard output). Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

you can use `sed` to eliminate the word label e.g.

```
grep "label:" | sed s/label://g
```

Comment: ... though the `grep` is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); `sed -n '/label:/s///gp'`

Answer (score 2):

Grep is a tool that can only be used for filtering lines of text. To do anything more complex, you probably need a more complex tool.

For example, `sed` can be used here:

```
sed 's/.*label: \(.*\)/\1/'
```

Text like this...

```
label: blue
llabel: red
label: green label: yellow
```

Gets turned into this:

```
blue
red
yellow
```

As you can see, this `sed` command only returns what comes after your search pattern, and multiple matches per lines aren't supported.